# Typecast eloquent relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have 2 models `Tour.php` and `Itinerary.php` in one to many relations:

**Tour.php**

```
    public function itinerary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itinerary', 'tour_id')->orderBy('day', 'asc');
}
```

**Itinerary.php**

```
    public function tour() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour', 'tour_id');
}
```

The `itineraries` table consists of the following columns:

> id |tour_id | day | detail

The `day` & `detail` column are of string type.

I want to print the itineraries of a tour according to ascending order of days.

How do I change the string to integer ?

I'm printing the output with foreach loop in the view:

```
@foreach($tour->itineraries as $item)
  {{$item->day}}
  {{$item->detail}}
@endforeach
```

I've tried cast method in model:

```
    protected $casts = [
    'day' => 'integer',
    ];
```

And Accessor

```
public function castDayToInt($value)
{
    return (int)$value;
}
```

but didn't get the expected result.

Current output of the above code:

- Day 1
- Day 11
- Day 12
- ....
- Day 2
- Day 20
- Day 21

Expected output

- Day 1
- Day 2
- Day 3
- .....
- Day 21

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the issue. What result are you expecting where when you do what? And what result are you currently getting? It just looks like you're echoing the value? When it's echoed, it's just text on the site anyway. HTML doesn't have any concept of "data types"

Comment: I found that your hasMany method is not plural, but you call it with plural

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm getting itineraries in this format `1`  `10` `11` `12`..`2``20``22` I'm expecting output in this format. `1` `2` `3`..`22`

Comment: So the actual question is really about the _order_ of the numbers? How are the `day` value stored in the db? As int or as varchar? Since the order/sorting happens in the database before it returns the data, it doesn't really matter if you cast the strings and int in Laravel _after_ the result comes from the db (already sorted)

Comment: It's varchar in the DB. I wonder why cast & accessor is not working

Comment: well first thing is that isn't an accessor, and why do you think casting this is going to help?

Comment: If the `day` value are integers and you want to them to be treated as such, change the database column to `int`. That's by far the easiest (and correct) way of solving your issue. Always tell the database what type of data it contains so it knows how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is change your day type in DB,

If you still need the varchar type, you can do it like this:

```php
public function itineraries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itinerary', 'tour_id')->orderByRaw('CONVERT(day, UNSIGNED) ASC');
}
```